# Simple image gallery plugin tags not being recognized

Tags: parsing, joomla, joomla-extensions, image-gallery

I am using a gallery plugin to show multiple images in a joomla article.

However when I add the code that needs to be parsed it just shows the code as plain text in my article, and the gallery is nowhere to be found.

This is the parsing code:

```
{gallery}content{/gallery}
```

With content being the image folder.

I enabled the plugin in plugin management, and when I put a non existent folder in the plugin code it gives me an error that the folder can't be found, so the plugin is active.

I removed all formatting from the code so that is not the issue.

I also set the cache folder permissions to 777 and 775, both did not work.

What could be the cause of this?

My joomla version is: `Joomla! 3.0.3 Stable [ Ember ] 04-February-2013 14:00 GMT`

Also I should note that when I type this code and save my article, the images from the specified folder are stored in the cache folder of the joomla root. So it is creating the thumbnails I guess.

Comment: Please immediately update your Joomla site to version 3.4.8. You're currently using a very old version that has big security vulnerabilities!!

Comment: I am using some custom stuff so I am a little hesitant with updating my whole joomla, I will take a look at it in the future. But this is not why the plugin is not working, since the plugin supports joomla version 3.x